# Why won't (Flask-)SQL Alchemy commit my changes even after I flag the attribute as modified?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy and trying to do a simple update and commit to a column in a table.

This is part of a larger application but all of the code that's causing me trouble is below:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import flag_modified
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Schedule(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    next = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def bump(self, days=7, minutes=0, seconds=0):
        self.next += timedelta(days=7, minutes=0, seconds=0)
        flag_modified(self, 'next')    
    def __init__(self):
        self.next = datetime.now()

def update():
    schedule = db.session.query(models.Schedule).first()
    print(schedule.next)
    schedule.bump()
    db.session.commit()
    print(schedule.next)
```

When I call `update()` I see the two dates printed out as I expect (separated by a week).

When I check the database `next` is still set to the original date.
When I turn on the setting to echo the SQL commands I only get the following:

```
2015-10-13 16:52:26,076 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT schedule.id AS schedule_id, schedule.next AS schedule_next 
FROM schedule 
 LIMIT %s
2015-10-13 16:52:26,076 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
```

With nothing being printed between the two dates (when `commit()` is called). I seem to be able to commit various other things in the application without difficulty but I can't seem to get this one to stick.

I tried importing `flag_modified` and marking the attribute dirty explicitly but still no luck.

One thing that I think might be relevant is that the update function is being called in an rqworker thread (using python-rq).

I'm not sure why this would prevent the data from being persisted but I can't think of anything else special about this code.